# Share photo with caption via facebook mobile app from my app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.0

I my app I need **to share photo with caption**.When using `Facebok Dialog` it is sharing. If I install `Facebook app` caption is not coming. Followed the instructions from `Facebook sdk latest version 4.2`.

Here is the code which I have used in my app for photo sharing.

```
private void postPhoto() {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
        SharePhoto sharePhoto = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).setCaption("gbsdfjhbsd").build();
        ArrayList<SharePhoto> photos = new ArrayList<>();
        photos.add(sharePhoto);

        SharePhotoContent sharePhotoContent =
                new SharePhotoContent.Builder().setPhotos(photos).setRef("hjgf").build();
        if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
            shareDialog.show(sharePhotoContent);
        } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {
            ShareApi.share(sharePhotoContent, shareCallback);
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
            // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when we get called back.
            LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithPublishPermissions(
                    this,
                    Arrays.asList(PERMISSION));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors, or is the image getting posted but without a caption? Have you also tried the latest version of the SDK (4.4)?

Comment: I didn't get any error.Posted without caption via Facebook app.If I uninstall that facebook app, with fb dialog it is posting image with caption.And I tried with 4.2 version.

Comment: That sounds like it might be a bug. You might want to report it at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to do the same thing. I found out that it is working if you set the bitmap on the builder like this:

```
// Build SharePhoto
SharePhoto.Builder photoBuilder = new SharePhoto.Builder();
photoBuilder.setBitmap(bitmap);
photoBuilder.setCaption("Caption");
final SharePhoto sharePhoto = photoBuilder.build();
```

(I am using facebook sdk version 4.5.2)

For some obscure reason if you use setImageUrl instead of setBitmap it no longer works :-(

To my understanding, this doesn't breach the facebook contract, because I am using it to add text that the user entered. I am merely bypassing the facebook dialog.